# How to unpack a spritesheet

Tags: spritesheet, texture-atlas, gdscript

The sprites are not aligned to a grid, they are packed as tightly as possible to preserve space (1px spacing). I tried using Alferd SpriteSheet Unpacker but it didn't work on my image because the format is nonstandard even though it's just a normal png image. I am trying to write a script with flood fill algorithm to determine where the sprites are, but I don't know how to detect where the images start and end.

```
func separate(image: Image) -> void:
    var images := 0
    image.lock()
    var start := {"position": Vector2(0, 0), "previous_blank": true}
    var checked_pixels := []
    var pixels := [start]
    while not pixels.empty():
        var dict: Dictionary = pixels.pop_back()
        var pixel: Vector2 = dict.position
        checked_pixels.append(dict)
        var blank: bool = image.get_pixelv(pixel).a == 0
        if not blank and dict.previous_blank:
            images += 1
        var neighbors := []
        if not pixel.x == image.get_width() - 1:
            neighbors.append({"position": Vector2(pixel.x + 1, pixel.y), "previous_blank": blank})
        if not pixel.y == image.get_height() - 1:
            neighbors.append({"position": Vector2(pixel.x, pixel.y + 1), "previous_blank": blank})
        for n in neighbors:
            var found_match := false
            for p in pixels:
                if p.position == n.position:
                    found_match = true
                    break
            if found_match:
                continue
            for c in checked_pixels:
                if c.position == n.position:
                    found_match = true
                    break
            if found_match:
                continue
            pixels.append(n)
    image.unlock()
    print(images)
```

Comment: I looked at the code for Alferd SpriteSheet Unpacker but I don't understand it. D:

Comment: Wouldn't your floodfill detect where images start and end? When you find an unmarked, non-transparent pixel, begin a floodfill spilling into all adjacent non-transparent pixels, marking them as you go. When the floodfill finishes, all the pixels it flooded are one sprite. Then you progress to the next unmarked non-transparent pixel and repeat. How does this differ from what you tried or what you need?

Comment: The problem is is that it doesn't end.

Comment: How does it not end? Every time you visit a non-transparent pixel, you mark it, and you skip visiting already-marked pixels. So the number of unmarked pixels must strictly decrease to zero, after which the algorithm terminates.

Comment: When I run it, it just keeps going and going. There must be an error somewhere.

Comment: nevermind it finally finished. it's way too slow!

Comment: Is your question then "how to make this code run faster?" ?

Comment: Yeah it is. Also it seems to fail on some images but i'm not sure why.

Comment: In what way does it fail? Be sure to document a specific test case for which it fails, and the specific symptoms of that failure that you observe.

Comment: Okay, will do that

Comment: I tagged this question with `gdscript`.  Please let me know or correct it if that is wrong.  Thanks!